# Trying to write a function inside a React component that truncates a string of text and adds an ellipsis after 15 words

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that displays the description of an item. I'm trying to truncate any descriptions that run on for longer that 15 words.

I wrote a function to do this but it keeps truncating the string after 15 characters instead of 15 words and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My function:

```
const truncateDescription = (description) => {
  description = description.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
  description = description.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
  description = description.replace(/\n /,"\n");

  descriptionLength = description.split(' ').length;
  return descriptionLength > 15 ? `${description.substring(0, 15)}...` : description;
}
```

My React Component:

```
const Item = ({ name, description }) => {
  return (
    <ItemContainer>
      <ItemName>{name}</ItemName>
      <ItemDescription>{truncateDescription(description)}</ItemDescription>
    </ItemContainer>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-wu-zbuok?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the words up, grab the length, then slice and re-join the words to the appropriate length.

I created a prop called `maxWordLength` that is used to limit the word length. By default, the value is set to `-1` (no-limit).

### App.jsx

```
import Item from "./Item";

const App = () => {
  const description =
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Item description={description} maxWordLength={15} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### Item.jsx

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const truncateDescription = (description, maxLength = -1) => {
  const words = description
    .trim()
    .replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ")
    .replace(/\n /, "\n")
    .split(" ");
  return maxLength !== -1 && words.length > maxLength
    ? `${words.slice(0, maxLength).join(" ")}...`
    : description;
};

const Item = (props) => {
  const { description, maxWordLength = -1 } = props;
  return <div>{truncateDescription(description, maxWordLength)}</div>;
};

Item.propTypes = {
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  maxWordLength: PropTypes.number
};

export default Item;
```